# Database connection error at Heroku: connect web app to Postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to deploy an application written on fastapi in heroku and connect it to the database.
To do this, I've added heroku-postgres (hobbi-dev) to the created project and then use database credentials in my web application code.

```
DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://qpvnasuzcvdwee:d3aecc71083e8f279851285095d9a8cb33f470c5838badaedc5ff1e3ce2df9c5@localhost:5432/detdicolajotpa"

# SQLAlchemy
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()

# databases query builder
database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

But at log cosole I get

```
2020-07-14T09:51:16.906646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app`
2020-07-14T09:51:19.630398+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-14T09:51:19.631018+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8499 (4)
2020-07-14T09:51:19.631118+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
2020-07-14T09:51:19.636402+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-14T09:51:19.645490+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-14T09:51:19.707669+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2020-07-14T09:51:19.759618+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:19 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
2020-07-14T09:51:20.176702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153843+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-14 09:51:22 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153882+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153884+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153885+00:00 app[web.1]:     return fn()
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153886+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153887+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153887+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153887+00:00 app[web.1]:     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153888+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153889+00:00 app[web.1]:     rec = pool._do_get()
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153889+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153890+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._dec_overflow()
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153890+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153890+00:00 app[web.1]:     exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153891+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153891+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153891+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153891+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._create_connection()
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153892+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153892+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153892+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153893+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153893+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153895+00:00 app[web.1]:     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153895+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153895+00:00 app[web.1]:     exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153895+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153896+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153896+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153896+00:00 app[web.1]:     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153897+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153897+00:00 app[web.1]:     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153897+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153898+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153898+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153898+00:00 app[web.1]:     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153899+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153899+00:00 app[web.1]:    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2020-07-14T09:51:22.153899+00:00 app[web.1]:    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

As I understand this string `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused` reports problems with connection to the base.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? On a local machine with similar settings, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `psycopg2` you need to install `psycopg2-binary` for Heroku

To get the connection parameters `os.environ`, don't try to connect directly, t's Heroku's recommended solution from [**Heroku Postgres**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python)

```
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

You shouldn't put credentials in your code, they haven been compromised, make sure to reset them before deploying your app with `heroku pg:credentials --reset` via Heroku console.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, I didn't get a chance to check your solution. As far as I can see now, the database connection error is gone. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Did you change your credentials, i think someone can reach your database with using your heroku posgres credentials.

Comment: if you're talking about credentials in a question, it's a fake values.